# Find Functions using beta version Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, version

A few days ago I received an email from Google Firebase that some of my cloud functions are using beta versions and they are removing the beta version calls If I understood correctly. So Now I have to update it. I Want to check that which of my function is calling the beta version I am not making static requests to any API. I am using firebase functions to call APIs and one of the function inside is calling firebase API. So Is there any possible way to know the function which is calling beta version API? I am Using `0.8.1` so It is because of this version that the function is calling beta API or is there something else? Here is my `Package.json`

```
{
"name": "functions",
"description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"dependencies": {
    "asyncawait": "^1.0.6",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1"
},
"private": true
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your functions in this project are using **very** old beta APIs.  You can tell because of this dependency:

```
"firebase-functions": "^0.8.1"
```

The [latest firebase-functions module](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases) is 3.5.0 at the time of this writing.  The APIs have changed significantly since 0.8.1, and your code (for non-http functions) will not work if you upgrade without changing your code.  You should consult the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to learn about the modern APIs.